# How to make hidden sidebar display on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, sidebar

So, I have Sidebar that hidden and shows up if I click a button to open it up.

this is on html:

```
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">News</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
   </div>
```

this is on css:

```
/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

this is javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px and add a black background color to body */
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
            document.getElementById("contoh").style.marginLeft = "250px";
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
        }

        /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0, and the background color of body to white */
        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("contoh").style.marginLeft = "0";
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
    </script>
```

my question is, how to change the button Open, to be on hover and display the full sidebar. Just like in sidebar from this web: https://la24.org/games-concept many thanks before.

Comment: Which element you want to hover? the button? or some part of the navbar? you can use `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` on the button. If what you want to hover is some part of the navbar (just like on the link you provided), based on  your mark-up. You can't. Because it shows there that your navbar has no width. Means no display. So how can you put your cursor over the element that has no display?

Comment: What I mean, I want to make like on the link I gave. So, I must display some width first, or display some icon, and when full width it will display all the menu, how I make that? @rmondesilva

Comment: yes. I posted an answer to show you an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@OP, Yes you have to put some width on your navbar. Just like how the navbar in the link you provided. No need to use JavaScript to open it. You can do it with simple CSS:

```
.sidenav {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50px; /* Put some width to hover on. */
}

/* ON HOVER */
.sidenav:hover{
   width: 250px;
}
```

```css
/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

/* ON HOVER */
.sidenav:hover{
   width: 250px;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">News</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: wow this is help me a lot, but my Javascript code is to make the main page (beside sidebar) is become darker when sidebar is full width. how use it with this code? thanks

Comment: @Rian just add every styles you have in your `function openNav()` inside the `.sidenav:hover{ /*here*/ }` .. like this: `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);`

Comment: thanks, I know now. last question, how do I trigger the css transition like from the Link I gave, so the mouse pointer is near to the sidebar (but not on the sidebar) the transition is on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try mouseover method and mouseout method of jQuery to solve this problem.

For example:

`$("#mySidenav").mouseover(function(){
    //Your code here.
})`

and

`$("#mySidenav").mouseout(function(){
    //Your code here.
})`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can implement using CSS also without writing javascript code. See below the code. 

<div class="parent">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">News</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
   </div>


.parent {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.parent:hover  .sidenav {
    display:block;
}


In the code mentioned by Dang Khoa, you have to include the button in side navigation or implement the onMouseHover on your button id.
```